# How to insert a data field into an empty table

Tags: oracle, vb6

I am making a front-end application in VB. The back-end is Oracle. I want an autogenerated ID on the click of a "New" button. It works well if data is present in  the table, but shows an error if the table is empty. What do I need to insert so that it works when I am using the application for the first time? My button code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmd_new_Click()
Call txt_clear
txt_name.Enabled = True
Set rsCat = New ADODB.Recordset
rsCat.Open "Category", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

If rsCat.EOF = rscat.BOF Then
    tempId = 1000
Else
    rsCat.MoveLast
    tempId = rsCat.Fields("Category_Id") + 1
End If

txt_Id = tempId
cmd_Save.Enabled = True
cmd_new = False

End Sub
```

Comment: although there is no error but in case table is empty it does go to if block instead it go to else block and give error of movelast.

Answer (score 0):

check rscat.RecordCount=-1
Basically, change

```
If rsCat.EOF = rscat.BOF Then
```

to

```
If rsCat.RecordCount=-1 Then
```